# UIWebView and top bar iPhone 5 iPhone 4 scaling issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

This is my WebView .nib File

[image: WebView Nib File]

The grey space on top is need for a 44px high Navigation bar, which is defined programmatically in a super class of the WebView.

The content of the Webview looks and scales correctly in iPhone 5. However on the iPhone 4s, different screen size, it scales wrongly, so that I can't scroll entirely to the top.

I set the Default-568h@2x.png, Default.png and Default@2x.png as start screens, because I read it can prevent scaling issues.

I also set the WebViewController´s view, which is the view in the Nib File to

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

but both doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer lies with auto layout. That seems like something really easy to do with it. Are you limited to a version of iOS that doesn't support auto layout? If not, here's how to do it:

[image][image][image]

Using this method, no matter what size of screen you have, you'll always have a 44 pixel margin at the top.